# Trying to print user specific number of stars, but console prints infinite

Tags: assembly, mips, subroutine, spim

Not really sure where I went wrong, in my program I prompt the user to type how many lines they want to be drawn to create a simple triangle with stars, yet when I type in a number, no matter the number, it instantly goes into an infinite loop and I have to close the program.  I can't seem to figure where it's getting stuck.  Here's my code.  Thanks!

```
    # $a1 holds how many lines
    # $a2 is the counter


    .text
    .globl main
main:

li $v0, 4
la $a0, size1
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

move $a1, $v0

ori $a2, $a2, 0

jal starline
nop

li $v0, 10
syscall

    .data
size1: .asciiz " How many lines do you want ? "
star: .asciiz "* "
newline: .asciiz " \n "


    .text
    .globl starline
starline:

loop:
beq $a1, $a2, endsub
nop

li $v0, 4
la $a0, star
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline
syscall

addu $a2, $a2, 1

j loop
nop


endsub:
jr $ra
nop
```

for example if the user types 2 the output should look like this

*

**

EDIT:  as I re-read what I typed I see why it only prints one star a line, however I'm still stuck on why it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Comment your code especially if you want others to help. Also, learn to use your simulator to step through the code and see why it is looping. Hint: it's a trivial mistake while trying to be clever with `ori $a2, $a2, 0`

Comment: Naah... really clever would be `or $a2, $a2, $zero` ... OP: spim simulators have debugger, use it. Programming in assembly without debugger is like trying to assemble a robot blindfolded... you can, if you insist, but it's much easier to *see* what you are doing.

Comment: @Ped7g: MIPS instructions are fixed length.  I don't think there's any reason to expect `ori` with an immediate zero to be worse than `or` with `$zero`.  If anything an immediate might be better, if it saves register read-port bottlenecks, if any MIPS microarchitectures have anything like that kind of problem.